# OpenCV.js DNN Load ONNX model (OpenCV JavaScript build)

Tags: javascript, opencv, onnx

Can't load onnx model on openCV js.

When I run the code  **netEmotion** return undefined.

This method work in haarcascade files.

Here is example code:

```js
var netEmotion = undefined;
   
utils.loadOpenCv(() => {
  var emotionModel = "emotion.onnx";
  utils.createFileFromUrl(emotionModel, emotionModel, () => {
  netEmotion = cv.readNetFromONNX(emotionModel);
  //netEmotion = cv.readNet(emotionModel);
});
```

This code from OpenCV js build:

```js
this.createFileFromUrl = function (path, url, callback) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        request.onload = function (ev) {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    let data = new Uint8Array(request.response);
                    cv.FS_createDataFile('/', path, data, true, false, false);
                    callback();
                } else {
                    self.printError('Failed to load ' + url + ' status: ' + request.status);
                }
            }
        };
        request.send();
    };
```